# Android can't call setAnchorView on material Snackbar

Tags: android, material-components, android-snackbar, material-components-android

this Snackbar is from package **[com.google.android.material.snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar)**. it extends **[BaseTransientBottomBar< Snackbar >](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar.html)** but there is no `snackbar.setAnchorView` or `snackbar.anchorView`.
Am I missing anything?

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
// Android
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

The method [`setAnchorView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar.html#setAnchorView(android.view.View)) [was introduced](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/868e80ed6ff183cceeb9c33523bf47f72772c52a#diff-c2f93dda98a890c61a837d7df74e9890) with **`1.1.0-alpha01`**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I changed to material:1.2.0-alpha01

Comment: @MasterZzzing If you prefer there is also 1.2.0-alpha02

Answer (score 0):

"view" in "make" method's arguments is that.
[image: android developer guide]

[Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar)

Comment: Thank you. in my case, I want my Snackbar to appear on the top of a button. As the document said, "Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to view" and this won't bring me what I want. So I will need to set Snackbar's anchor to that button to make it work